# AnyLogic browser in localhost closes when refreshed. How do I not make it close when refreshed?

Tags: javascript, java, anylogic, ini

I am trying to run my AnyLogic model in a locally hosted chrome browser which I have managed to do so by configuring the com.anylogic.engine.ini file. However, whenever I try to refresh the browser, the browser will close. Is there any way that I can make the browser not close when being refreshed?

Thanks for the help in advance!

This are the lines of code in my com.anylogic.engine.ini file:

`standaloneBrowserPath=C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe`
`standaloneBrowserCommandArguments=$1`
`standaloneServerPort=12345`

Comment: Why do you refresh in the first place? I have never had any need to refresh the browser, running AnyLogic models...

Comment: Appreciate if you can just answer the question.

Comment: I can't , but was hoping that your answer might open a new perspective on the actual problem, hence my follow-up question :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you can't. Because Animation Window detect closing with listen for Unload Event and refresh in the browser trigger this event.